# Character Smaller Than a Space in Java?

Tags: java, string, output

I'm making a program in Java and I need a character that is like the space (" "), except smaller in length when it is displayed.  Ideally the character would be half the size of the space character.

I was wondering if such a character exists, or if there is a way for me to modify the length of the space character to make it smaller when outputted to the user.

Comment: This is not a Java question but a rendering question, how are you displaying this text.  On a web page, via Swing, something else...

Comment: This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you want a half-space?  If you’re trying to line up text, space width is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: +VGR For my program, I'm outputting a single digit number on one line, and on the next line right under it I have two dashes.  I want to get the number centered above the dashes, since right now it's just directly above the left one.  If I push the number to the right using a space key, it will be just above the right one.  My only solution I can think of would be to use a smaller space key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [this article](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html). This may help:

```
U+0020  SPACE   foo bar Depends on font, typically 1/4 em, often adjusted
U+00A0  NO-BREAK SPACE  foo bar As a space, but often not adjusted
U+1680  OGHAM SPACE MARK    foo bar Unspecified; usually not really a space but a dash
U+180E  MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR   foo᠎bar No width
U+2000  EN QUAD foo bar 1 en (= 1/2 em)
U+2001  EM QUAD foo bar 1 em (nominally, the height of the font)
U+2002  EN SPACE    foo bar 1 en (= 1/2 em)
U+2003  EM SPACE    foo bar 1 em
U+2004  THREE-PER-EM SPACE  foo bar 1/3 em
U+2005  FOUR-PER-EM SPACE   foo bar 1/4 em
U+2006  SIX-PER-EM SPACE    foo bar 1/6 em
```

Comment: thanks.  How would I use these different characters in Java?  I don't know anything about Unicode.

Comment: You can use escape character, like this: `\u0020`